# Query which spans and follows back several tables

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

My question is about creating a query which filter objects that are related through several intermediate tables. My relational database looks like this:

[image]

Any number of products can be uploaded by one user (one to many relationship). However, users also can rank products. A ranking can be completed by several users and a user can have several rankings (Many to many relationship). The same applies between Product and Ranking. I use explicit intermediate tables (Rank and Belong) which defines the M2M relationships by the through parameter, because they have additional information which describes the relationship.

The models code is something like this (I omitted irrelevant fields for simplicity):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    belong= models.ManyToManyField(Ranking, through="Belong")
    #...

#The M2M table which relates Product and Ranking
class Belong(models.Model):
    ranking = models.ForeignKey(Ranking, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("ranking", "product"))

class Ranking(models.Model):
    user= models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through="Rank")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #...

#The M2M table which relates User and Ranking
class Rank(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ranking = models.ForeignKey(Ranking, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "ranking"))

#The AUTH_USER_MODEL, which is not included here
```

My question is: How can I create a query which filters products which has been ranked by a given user? This implies “following back” relations between Belong, Ranking and Rank tables. I tried this following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), but it didn´t work:

```
Product.objects.filter(belong__ranking__rank__user=”username”)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a bit confused between your M2M relationships, and their through models.

For example, I don't understand why your M2M from Product to Ranking is called "belong". It should be called "rankings". Your M2M from Ranking to User at least has the right basic name, but it points to many users so should be "users".

Nevertheless, the point is that when you follow the M2Ms, you don't need to take the through tables into account. And the other issue is that "user" is itself a model, so to compare with a username you would need to continue to follow to that field. So:

```
Product.objects.filter(belong__user__username="username")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, the names are not the most convenient, I will fix it in my code.